# Oracle APEX 4.2 primary Key?

Tags: oracle-apex

All,

Just a quick question. Is there still a restriction on APEX on the number of separate columns that a primary key can be built on?

In previous versions, APEX only supports upto 2 column primary key?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

Yes that restriction still exists.  However, in the next release (Apex 4.1) I have heard that there will be the option to use ROWID instead of the primary key for forms, which will overcome this limitation.

See the [Statement of Direction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-sod-087560.html):

> Use of ROWID – Allow usage of ROWID
>   for Automatic DML processing (as an
>   alternative to identifying the PK
>   columns).